# How to notify an Activity when a Service fired an action

Tags: java, android

I created a timer and I've implemented a `Service` that sends a notification to the user when the timer ends.
When the timer stops I play an Audio file that continues until the user stops it by clicking "OK" on a `DialogFragment`, but when the app is in background and I click on the notification the Sound keep going because the `DialogFragment` doesn't popup, What I want to know is: is it possible to notify the `TimerActivity` from the service so when the notification is opened I show the `DialogFragment` or I stop the sound?

This is my `Service` code:

```
public class ScheduledService extends IntentService {

    public ScheduledService() {
        super("My service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Do something, fire a notification or whatever you want to do here
        Log.d("debug", "Ring Rind !");

        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CookingTimer.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("This is a sample notification")
                .setContentText("Subject")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
          (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for this as this is basically what you are looking for. On Android you can implemented it yourself (1 screen of code) or use existing implementations if you wish like EventBus like [OTTO](https://github.com/square/otto) or [GreenRobot's](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: Ok I'll read the documentation now! Before starting, do you know if this solution works also for API 9? Because i'm targeting API 9+

Comment: But what do you care API9 for? Nobody uses it already - see https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/about/dashboards/index.html And even if for any reason you do not like neither of existing buses, implementing own is pretty simple - just option to register listener and code to fire the event notification.

Comment: "Thanks" to analytics we saw that lot of customers still has Android 2.3 so we decided to develop for API 9+.. I'd like to at least to start from API 11+.. we'll see :D Thank you anyways, i'll read the documentation when possible

Comment: I personally do not care anything below Android 4.0 for some time now, but what I'd suggest to check either requirements or build sample app against lowest API you want to support and see if there're any issues. If there're are, implement this pattern yourself - it's pretty trivial